# Reporting Services Service Application Authentication Error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have "inherited" a small SharePoint farm with an App SP server and a database. The cilent wishes to use PowerView. Reporting Services seems to be configured correctly (but apparently isn't). When trying to build PowerView reports or browsing to Manage Reporting Services Service Application-> System Settings, I get an internal server error and the following error shows up in the ULS:

> An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the Reporting Services Service Application mapped to this web application is available OR the report server is available and configured for SharePoint Integrated mode. --> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' 
>    
>        
>           Could not find permission set named 'ASP.Net'. 
>            
>            
>            body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
>            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
>            b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
>            H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red } 
>            H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon } 
>            pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt} 
>            .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;} 
>            .version {color: gray;} 
>            .error {margin-bottom: 10px;} 
>            .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; } 
>            @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {'. --> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' 
>    
>        
>           Could not find permission set named 'ASP.Net'. 
>            
>            
>            body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
>            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
>            b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
>            H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red } 
>            H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon } 
>            pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt} 
>            .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;} 
>            .version {color: gray;} 
>            .error {margin-bottom: 10px;} 
>            .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; } 
>            @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {'. --> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please download  SQL reporting add-in on sharepoint server and install .In my case its working fine

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35583

Answer (score -1):

Edit the Basic Settings of the application pool to use .NET version 2.0 instead of 4.0.